# OAuth vk sdk (Android studio)

Tags: android, oauth

Пишу приложение для работы со списком друзей.
Мне необходима авторизация только через OAuth
Когда пишу VKSdk.login() если на телефоне есть установленное приложение ВК то он запускает именно его и работает с ним. А если нет - то вылезает OAuth вход.

Как сделать чтобы всегда(насильно) был вход через OAuth вне зависимости от того стоит приложение вк на телефоне или нет?

Comment: Вечером постараюсь ответить на ваш вопрос)